# Which is the equivalent of this VB6 code to VBNET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6

The purpose of this VB6 code is to return the current playing filename (not title) of WinAmp.

This is the lines I need to translate to VBNET:

```
Temp = StrConv(Buffer, vbUnicode)
strFileName = Left$(Temp, InStr(Temp, Chr$(0)) - 1)
```

Buffer is a Byte type, temp and strFileName are string types.

Also here:

```
Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal lpBaseAddress As Long, ByRef lpBuffer As Byte, ByVal nSize As Long, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long) As Long
```

...I've changed "ByRef lpBuffer As Any" to "ByRef lpBuffer As Byte" (I think I did the correct change there)

This is the full code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpszClassName As String, ByVal lpszWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByRef lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal lpBaseAddress As Long, ByRef lpBuffer As Byte, ByVal nSize As Long, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

    Private Const PROCESS_VM_READ As Long = &H10
    Private Const WM_USER As Long = &H400
    Private Const IPC_GETPLAYLISTFILE As Long = 211
    Private Const IPC_GETLISTPOS As Long = 125
    Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260
    Private hWndWinamp As Long

    Private Function GetWinampWindow() As Long
        GetWinampWindow = FindWindow("Winamp v1.x", vbNullString)
    End Function

    Public Function GetPlayingFileName() As String
        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim lp As Long, lpWinamp As Long
        Dim iIndex As Long
        Dim PID As Long
        Dim bRet As Long
        Dim dwRead As Long
        Dim Buffer(MAX_PATH) As Byte
        Dim Temp As String

        hWndWinamp = GetWinampWindow

        If hWndWinamp = 0 Then
            GetPlayingFileName = ""
            Exit Function
        End If

        iIndex = SendMessage(hWndWinamp, WM_USER, 0, IPC_GETLISTPOS)

        lp = SendMessage(hWndWinamp, WM_USER, iIndex, IPC_GETPLAYLISTFILE)

        If lp = 0 Then
            GetPlayingFileName = ""
            Exit Function
        End If

        Call GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWndWinamp, PID)

        lpWinamp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, PID)

        If lpWinamp = 0 Then
            GetPlayingFileName = ""
            Exit Function
        End If

        bRet = ReadProcessMemory(lpWinamp, lp, Buffer(0), MAX_PATH, dwRead)

        Call CloseHandle(lpWinamp)

        Temp = StrConv(Buffer, vbUnicode)

        strFileName = Left$(Temp, InStr(Temp, Chr$(0)) - 1)

        GetPlayingFileName = strFileName

    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MsgBox(GetPlayingFileName())
    End Sub

End Class
```

> UPDATE

This is the updated code following the suggestions, but it is failling in the try/catch line with an error: **STARTINDEX CANNOT BE LESS THAN ZERO**

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpszClassName As String, ByVal lpszWindowName As String) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetWindowThreadProcessId Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByRef lpdwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function ReadProcessMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, ByVal lpBaseAddress As Long, ByRef lpBuffer As Byte, ByVal nSize As Long, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

    Private Const PROCESS_VM_READ As Long = &H10
    Private Const WM_USER As Long = &H400
    Private Const IPC_GETPLAYLISTFILE As Long = 211
    Private Const IPC_GETLISTPOS As Long = 125
    Private Const MAX_PATH As Long = 260
    Private hWndWinamp As Long

    Private Function GetWinampWindow() As Long
        GetWinampWindow = FindWindow("Winamp v1.x", vbNullString)
    End Function

    Public Function GetPlayingFileName() As String
        Dim strFileName As String
        Dim lp As Long, lpWinamp As Long
        Dim iIndex As Long
        Dim PID As Long
        Dim bRet As Long
        Dim dwRead As Long
        Dim Buffer(MAX_PATH) As Byte
        Dim Temp As String

        hWndWinamp = GetWinampWindow()

        If hWndWinamp = 0 Then
            GetPlayingFileName = ""
            Exit Function
        End If

        iIndex = SendMessage(hWndWinamp, WM_USER, 0, IPC_GETLISTPOS)

        lp = SendMessage(hWndWinamp, WM_USER, iIndex, IPC_GETPLAYLISTFILE)

        If lp = 0 Then
            GetPlayingFileName = ""
            Exit Function
        End If

        Call GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWndWinamp, PID)

        lpWinamp = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, 0, PID)

        If lpWinamp = 0 Then
            GetPlayingFileName = ""
            Exit Function
        End If

        bRet = ReadProcessMemory(lpWinamp, lp, Buffer(0), MAX_PATH, dwRead)

        Call CloseHandle(lpWinamp)

        ' Original VB6 code
        'Temp = StrConv(Buffer, vbUnicode)
        'strFileName = Left$(Temp, InStr(Temp, Chr$(0)) - 1)

        Temp = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetString(Buffer)

        Try
            strFileName = Temp.Substring(Temp.IndexOf(CChar("0")) - 1)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

        GetPlayingFileName = strFileName

    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        MsgBox(GetPlayingFileName())
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: The many redundant empty lines make this code *really* hard to read because you have to scroll the whole time.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Sorry I've posted the code as is without removing the empty lines. EDIT: I've modified the code now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember to import system.text

```
dim aux as UnicodeEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding
temp = aux.GetString(buffer)
strfilename = temp.substring(temp.indexof(cchar("0"))-1)
```

Comment: Hello, I've imported system.text but The first line throws this error: type UnicodeEncoding.GetString is not defined, the second line (First I've needed to change the '' quotes to "") throws this error: Operator '-' is not defined for types 'Char' and 'Integer'

Comment: There is a bracket missing: `strFileName = temp.substring(temp.indexof(CChar("0")) - 1)`

Comment: oh @Andrew Gibson thanks, now the problem is only with the buffer line string conversion

Comment: Yeah, that's why i get for posting it without trying it first. editing the answer right now

Comment: Finally changed those two vb6 lines for this: Return System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.Default.GetString(Buffer)

Comment: No need to instantiate `UnicodeEncoding` – and in fact it’s not recommended. Use the `Encoding.Unicode` object instead. Furthermore, `CChar("0")` can (and should) be written as `"0"c`, and neither is the same as `Chr$(0)`. In fact, the latter is simply `Chr(0)` – but I actually suspect that it’s unnecessary in the code anyway if the string is properly encoded.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent in VB.NET to converting to unicode with `StrConv()` is [Encoding.Convert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdcak6ye.aspx).

The equivalent to `Left()` is [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and to `Instr()` is [String.IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx).

**Added** In answer to the error message, InStr() indexes from 1, not 0 (VB.NET). You'll need to make adjustments to such values.

Comment: Thanks but the problem is when I try to convert the buffer to a string like in the original vb6 code... I've tried your suggestion but nothing: Temp = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.Default, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, Buffer)

Comment: Hamster has suggested the alternative: `UnicodeEncoding`. Try that.

Comment: I hesitate to mention this - and I am not recommending it, but if you want to be able to run and test the code, you could TEMPORARILY add `Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic` at the top and still use these VB6 functions. I only mention this as an aid to testing, not as a long-term solution. Personally, I wouldn't do this. Bite the bullet and find the proper equivalents! Andy

Comment: I've imported "Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic" but still the same errors in original code I've posted

Comment: You haven't told us anything about the errors you are receiving (or mentioned them before).

Comment: The errors are this after importing, vbunicode: vbunicode is not declared      Chr$(0):Type character '$' does not match declared data type 'Char'.

Comment: I would remove the dollar signs (they shouldn't be necessary, or can be avoided with property typing). If you have to, use the number 64 for `vbUnicode`. But, as I say, you would be better of getting the VB.NET versions of the functions working.